# What does a simple bijection imply on cardinals for which the function is defined?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I asked myself and also proved both theoritically and intuitively that we have the following implication. Please prove me right or wrong.

$$(f:E\rightarrow F\quad is\quad a\quad bijection)\Rightarrow (Card(E)\le Card(F))$$

**And here follows my proof:**

Let $E$ and $F$ be two arbitrary sets.

Assume that $f:E\rightarrow F$ is a bijection. Then, we have;

$$\forall x\in E,\quad \exists !y\in F\quad |\quad f(x)=y$$

Lets choose any $x\in E$, so that we have $f(x)\in F$.

We have here that $(x,f(x))\in (E\times F)$ is a unique couple.

Thus,

$$Card(F)=Card\left\{ \forall x\in E, (x,f(x)) \right\} $$

We will have to study now the two case between $Card(E)$ and $Card\left\{ \forall x\in E, (x,f(x)) \right\}$:

1st case:

Have we any $x\in E$ such that $f(x)=\emptyset$? But, obviously, this will result into a contradiction with our assumption for bijective definition of the function $f$, because of the unicity & existence are part of predicate.

2nd case:

Have we any $y\in F$ such that $f^{ -1 }\left( y \right)=\emptyset$? We can though easily observe that existence of such $y$ is obvious, because we would conclude then that $f$ is injective -which is included within assumption.

So, there may exist at least one such $y\in F$ which doesn't have reciprocal image in $E$

Consequently,

We deduce that;

$$Card(F)\ge Card(E)$$
$$\Box $$

**PS: I've forced myself for a forward implicative reasonning, though it would be easier by contradiction perhaps.**

Comment: $\forall x\in E,\quad \exists !y\in F\quad |\quad f(x)=y$ isn't the definition of a bijection. It's the definition of a function $f:E\mapsto F$. Besides, "$(x, f(x)))$ is a unique couple" doesn't make much sense : every couple $(a,b)$ is "unique".

Comment: If you have a bijection $E \to F$ then $\# E = \# F$.

Comment: A bijection is an injection. The definition of $|E|\leq |F|$ is "There exists an injection $E\to F$".

Comment: Thank you a lot. Appearantly, I used a mislead definition for bijection, which confused my thoughts. As you let me see the error, I'm comfortable with answers to my question.

Comment: Regarding your deleted question: $B \subseteq C$. Assume not, i.e. for some $x$ we have : $x \in B$ and $x \notin C$. Then $x \notin A$ (otherwise $x \in A \cap B \subseteq A \cap C \subseteq C$). But $x \in B$ implies $x \in A \cup B \subseteq A \cup C$, contradicting the fact that E$x \notin A$ and $x \notin C$.

Comment: I thank you a lot. You can't know how much your answer is valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thank you a lot for commenting my question. Indeed, the error on my behalf was to consider wrong assumptions regarding definitions I used.

I'm writing this prompt reply to make it clear that, resuming commentors' remarks:

It's a function which is defined as:
$$\forall x\in E,\quad \exists !y\in F\quad |\quad f(x)=y$$

But for bijection, we have:
$$\forall y\in F,\quad \exists !x\in E\quad |\quad f(x)=y$$

And, for the relation between bijectivity and cardinilities are exactly:

1. if $f$ bijective, $Card(E)=Card(F)$
2. if $f$ injective, $Card(E)\le Card(F)$

Thank you very much again.